# Pointer using Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, roi

I would like to get a pointer(*A) of a Region of interest in an Image( I ). It is good for me because I can atribute this region for an other Mat M(Same size that region *A). I would like, for example to sum the original region for M:

*A += M;

It could be because I don't need to sum each pixel of the image. Can anyone help me how can I get this pointer of a ROI or how can I use this ROI to sum a other Mat M?

Comment: if you're using cv::Mat, please use references( & ), not pointers. those things got built-in refcounts, if you're passing around pointers, you *will* trash those sooner or later.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want. Are you just trying to operate on a region of interest?